# Programmatically bind DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

Here is my code:

```
foreach (var columnData in lookup.DataProvider.Metadata)
    {
        DataGridColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn { Binding = new Binding(columnData.FieldName) };

        if (columnData.DataType == typeof(bool))
        {
            column = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn { Binding = new Binding(columnData.FieldName) };
        }

        if (columnData.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            //... ????
        }

        column.Header = columnData.Caption;

        DataDataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
    }
```

Basically, I'm creating columns and bindings in code because columns not known at design-time.

Now I need to add templated column and not sure how to write it in C#. Here is example of XAML of column I need to add:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Received" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="SomeTime">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MyControls:MyDateTimeLabel DisplayUtcDate="{Binding SomeTime}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**EDIT**

In case someone interested. I used solution from here: http://www.pettijohn.com/2011/01/silverlight-datagrid-with-dynamic.html

I took version with XAML loader. It definitely smells since I got my namespaces etc hardcoded into strings.

So, I started to explore second choice. Here is how my dynamic column looks now:

```
column = new DataGridTemplateColumn
            {
                CanUserSort = true,
                SortMemberPath = columnData.FieldName,
                CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["DateTimeColumnDataTemplate"]
            };
```

I'm loading `DateTemplate` from resources. This was cool, but how do I do binding? Suggestion here was to get to my DateTimeLabel and set binding. But that didn't work(see article on why). So, I wrote this code and all is well:

```
private void OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridColumn t in this.DataDataGrid.Columns)
        {
            if (t is DataGridTemplateColumn)
            {
                var label = t.GetCellContent(e.Row) as DitatDateTimeLabel;
                label.SetBinding(DitatDateTimeLabel.DisplayUtcDateProperty, new Binding(t.SortMemberPath));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shot in the dark, probably not the case (I've not expertise in silverlight/xaml) but isn't there something like `.DataBind()`?

Comment: Yes, but I want control over what columns, what headers, etc.

Comment: Linq has a `.Select()` extension method on all `IEnumerable<T>`'s, can you use that with an anonymous type to control it? (Again I have no idea how silverlight works, so it's just a guess from my experience with other fields of MS programming.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put your `DataTemplate` inside `Page`/`UserControl` resources, retrieve it in code and apply to your column's `CellTemplate`. It would look sth like this:

`column.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["DateTimeFieldTemplate"];`

The binding should work as it is in your `DataTemplate` XAML right now because on the `DataGrid` row level your `DataContext` will be set to the item itself.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I did it "bad" way: http://www.pettijohn.com/2011/01/silverlight-datagrid-with-dynamic.html
This article also shows your suggestion and I would go with it but how do I dynamically specify which field by `DisplayUtcDate` binds to. I really like to do what you suggest but so far can't figure how to do that

Comment: If you have the `DataTemplate` loaded you can do `DependencyObject content = template.LoadContent()`. If the data template is as you presented in your code the `content` will be your `MyDateTimeLabel` control. You can then set the binding dynamicaly using SetBinding method on your control. It would look sth like this `((MyDateTimeLabel)content).SetBinding(MyDateTimeLabel.DisplayUtcDateProperty, someBinding)` where `someBinding` is a binding to some property (similiar to what you've done for `CheckBox` or `TextBox`)

Comment: See my edit. I had to set binding on each row load, otherwise it wasn't working. But now I'm good with no XAML strings in code. Thanks for useful pointers!